# AWS S3 access denied

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When i upload a file using Java SDK to S3 bucket and try to download it from the AWS console by clicking download, i get access denied . However i can still download it using Java SDK . I tried to configure access from the console for any authenticated user but did not let me to download the file. I added a bucket policy to allow root download/Upload delet and list but did not help too.

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(keyName, sKey);
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(S3BucketName,fileName, file));
```

I tried to get the policy suing Java SDK but i get request denied .

Do you see where is the problem ?

Comment: You must check on AWS SCRACHPAD

Comment: Could you explain more about your suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **give permission** to access file publically, liek this:

```
s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(S3BucketName,fileName, file, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ));
```

Comment: Your solution is working and has guided me to find a good response.

Comment: @JavaMain glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Please look over here .....

And check your credential and XML which you want to post .....

just chose you desired feed on MWS scratched and get your result .

https://mws.amazonservices.in/scratchpad/index.html

I hope it will help ..
There is no other option to check and get easily data from MWS API

Comment: What you suggested is for Sellers and i am simple user and did not see the relation between downloading simple text file from S3 (read my question)  and Scratchpad .

Comment: you have need to read documentation of scratchpad. please read first